# How do I enable my Android Application users to download a WebView for later use dart and Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

Hi I'm trying to create a reading app that allows user to save pages for offline use from my online learning website. It uses the web view widget to access the webpage.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

 class ScholarshipsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _ScholarshipsPageState createState() => _ScholarshipsPageState();
 }

 class _ScholarshipsPageState extends State<ScholarshipsPage> {
 Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Scholarship Research Program'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      elevation: 0,
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: WebView(
              initialUrl: 'https://mydigitalbackpack.net/scholarshipresearchprogram/',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
    )
    );
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the `webview_flutter` plugin because those features are missing.

Instead, you can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

In your case, you can use the `InAppWebViewController.android.saveWebArchive` method to save the current WebView as a web archive. At the moment, this method is available only for Android (it is implemented through the [WebView#saveWebArchive](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#saveWebArchive(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) official Android API)!

I will check how to implement the same thing for iOS if possible.

Instead, if you need to download files: to be able to recognize downloadable files, you need to set the `useOnDownloadStart: true` option, and then you can listen the `onDownloadStart` event!

Also, for example, on Android you need to add write permission inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then, you need to ask permission using the [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin. Instead, to effectively download your file, you can use the [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) plugin.

Here is a complete example using http://ovh.net/files/ (in particular, the http://ovh.net/files/1Mio.dat as URL) to test the download:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
      debug: true // optional: set false to disable printing logs to console
  );
  await Permission.storage.request();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
            initialUrl: "http://ovh.net/files/1Mio.dat",
            initialHeaders: {},
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                useOnDownloadStart: true
              ),
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              webView = controller;
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

            },
            onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

            },
            onDownloadStart: (controller, url) async {
              print("onDownloadStart $url");
              final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                url: url,
                savedDir: (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path,
                showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
                openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
              );
            },
          ))
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here, as you can see, I'm using also the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) plugin to get the folder where I want to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer if you are the owner of the html page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59899281/5513788

If not, see here: [Flutter - How to download files in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57937664/5513788) and here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26373. Basically it's not possible at the moment.

For my app, what I did was set this up natively in Android using Java and that worked very well.