# Flutter - Can't download files from Webview

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, download

When I click any download button from inside my webview, it does nothing. I couldn't find any solution yet, so I'm asking here. Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937664/flutter-how-to-download-files-in-webview. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937664/flutter-how-to-download-files-in-webview/62116695#62116695

Comment: Which plugin you have used ? webview_flutter or flutter_webview_plugin??

Answer (score 0):

What you have inside a webView can't be handled from the app, you load a url in your web view so everything goes inside the webView is related to the url that you have loaded.
what you can do with web view is fore example just refreshing it by swipe refresh.
or handling state by :

```
inner class WebClientCustom : WebViewClient(){

    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, error: WebResourceError?) {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, errorCode: Int, description: String, failingUrl: String) {
    }

}
```