# How to download files in Flutter WebView?

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I am working on Flutter webview apps using [Flutter Webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child : const WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I try to use launchURL plugin but that will open predefined url in external browser window.

```
if (url.contains('.pdf')) {
    launchURL(url);
  }
```

What I want is to download the file in-app webview.

Comment: I done this but i used flutter_inapp_webview plugin

Comment: this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937664/flutter-how-to-download-files-in-webview

Answer (score -1):

There is actually an existing package that you could use. Check the [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) package:

> A plugin for creating and managing download tasks. Supports iOS and
> Android.
>
> This plugin is using `WorkManager` on Android and
> `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` on iOS to run download tasks in background.

Here is an [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader/example) that you can try:

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
> import 'package:flutter_downloader_example/home_page.dart';
>
> void main() async {
>   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
>   await FlutterDownloader.initialize(debug: true, ignoreSsl: true);
>
>   runApp(const MyApp());
> }
>
> class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
>   const MyApp({super.key});
>
>   static const _title = 'flutter_downloader demo';
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     final platform = Theme.of(context).platform;
>
>     return MaterialApp(
>       title: _title,
>       theme: ThemeData.light(),
>       darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
>       home: MyHomePage(
>         title: _title,
>         platform: platform,
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: The question is about how to download using webview. The answer provided here does not take into account the context of webview when downloading. Does not answer the question