# Flutter handle on click events in Webview

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-layout, android-webview, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to build webview in my mobile application

In the webview when click on search all the records to particular time period are shown it works but when click on `Export To Excel` button it should download the `excel sheet` but nothing works in my application..

Below is the code what I have done

Thanks for help!![enter image description here][1]

PS: URL hidden for security reasons..

`

```
   Stack(
       children: [
      Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: progress < 1.0
              ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: progress,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                )
              : Container()),
      WebView(
        initialUrl:
            "URL",
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
          _webViewController = controller;
        },
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          setState(() {
            this.progress = progress / 100;
          });
        },
        onPageFinished: (finish) {
          setState(
            () {
              isLoading = false;
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937664/flutter-how-to-download-files-in-webview and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247542/how-to-download-create-pdf-through-webview-in-flutter

Comment: Tried those methods but still not working..
In my application when clicked on button, `webview` is opened and in the same website there's option to `download excel file` how can i achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

Use **navigationDelegate** parameter in Webview constructor.

```js
WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
  navigationDelegate: (action) {
    if (action.url.contains('mail.google.com')) {
      print('Trying to open Gmail');
      Navigator.pop(context); // Close current window
      return NavigationDecision.prevent; // Prevent opening url
    } else if (action.url.contains('youtube.com')) {
      print('Trying to open Youtube');
      return NavigationDecision.navigate; // Allow opening url
    } else {
      return NavigationDecision.navigate; // Default decision
    }
  },
),
```

That's it. Enjoy coding!