# How do i enable downloads in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm new in flutter. I am working on a mobile app that displays certain pages of a website, one of the pages has a link through which users/visitors can download a PDF file. This link works in most regular browsers I have tried, but when I click it in my app, it doesn't. I am using "WebviewScaffold" to display the pages. Please how do I solve this problem.
 Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A similar issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247542/how-to-download-create-pdf-through-webview-in-flutter) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247542/how-to-download-create-pdf-through-webview-in-flutter/)! I report here the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62116620/4637638) that I gave to the similar issue:

You can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews. It can recognize downloadable files in both Android (using `setDownloadListener`) and iOS platforms!

To be able to recognize downloadable files, you need to set the `useOnDownloadStart: true` option, and then you can listen the `onDownloadStart` event!

Also, for example, on Android you need to add write permission inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then, you need to ask permission using the [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin. Instead, to effectively download your file, you can use the [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) plugin.

Here is a complete example using http://ovh.net/files/ (in particular, the http://ovh.net/files/1Mio.dat as URL) to test the download:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
      debug: true // optional: set false to disable printing logs to console
  );
  await Permission.storage.request();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
            initialUrl: "http://ovh.net/files/1Mio.dat",
            initialHeaders: {},
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                debuggingEnabled: true,
                useOnDownloadStart: true
              ),
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              webView = controller;
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

            },
            onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

            },
            onDownloadStart: (controller, url) async {
              print("onDownloadStart $url");
              final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                url: url,
                savedDir: (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path,
                showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
                openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
              );
            },
          ))
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here, as you can see, I'm using also the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) plugin to get the folder where I want to save the file.

Comment: How can we download if data is coming from API call?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter webview is currently in developers preview and there is a lot of functionalities that are not developed yet, including downloading files.
If the download works in regular browsers you might wanna use the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package instead of a webview to open your url in your phone's browser and download it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step-by-step solution to download files in the flutter web view app.
Flutter web view does not allow downloading files and images directly same as a browser. Because your web view app should have storage access permission.

You may be using the **webview_flutter** or **flutter_inappwebview** plugin solution will be the same for both you will be getting a callback of the download request.

We will be using the following plugins to achieve download functionality in the flutter web view app :

> **android_path_provider**  (to access file storage path in android)

> **flutter_downloader** (to listen to the download event and start download)

> **permission_handler** ( for handling permissions)

> **path_provider** ( for accessing storage path /directory)

Now please add the latest versions of the above plugins to your **pubspec.yaml** file or else run the following command in your terminal :

```
flutter pub add android_path_provider
flutter pub add flutter_downloader
flutter pub add permission_handler
flutter pub add path_provider
```

Initialize flutter **FlutterDownloader** in main.dart file :

```
    await FlutterDownloader.initialize(
      debug: false, // optional: set to false to disable printing logs to console (default: true)
      ignoreSsl : true // option: set to false to disable working with http links (default: false)
  );
```

Inside android> app >src > main > AndroidManifest.xml :
Add these permissions to the manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Inside  tag of the manifest file add the following code :

```
 <provider
       android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
       android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
           android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
   </provider>
```

now create a download_helper_functions.dart file and create these functions in that file :

```
late String localPath;

Future<void> prepareSaveDir() async {
  localPath = (await findLocalPath())!;
  final savedDir = Directory(localPath);
  bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
  if (!hasExisted) {
    savedDir.create();
  }
  return ;
}

Future<String?> findLocalPath() async {
  var externalStorageDirPath;
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    try {
      externalStorageDirPath = await AndroidPathProvider.documentsPath;
    } catch (e) {
      final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      externalStorageDirPath = directory?.path;
    }
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    externalStorageDirPath =
        (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).absolute.path;
  }
  return externalStorageDirPath;
}
```

now inside you webview widget  declaration  or InAppWebView widget we have a callback **onDownloadStart** or **onDownloadStartRequest**  so add this code to the download callback :

```
 onDownloadStartRequest: (controller, DownloadStartRequest request) async {
            //todo download catelog here
            FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
            final platform = Theme.of(context).platform;
            bool value = await _checkPermission(platform);
            if(value){
              await prepareSaveDir();
              {
                final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                  url: request.url.toString(),
                  savedDir: localPath,
                  showNotification: true,
                  saveInPublicStorage: true,// show download progress in status bar (for Android)
                  openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
                );
              }
            }
          },
```

and now inside your dart where you have declared webview create these two functions :

```
Future<bool> _checkPermission(platform) async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) return true;
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    if (platform == TargetPlatform.android &&
        androidInfo.version.sdkInt! <= 28) {
      final status = await Permission.storage.status;
      // final status2 = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        final result = await Permission.storage.request();
        // final result2 = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
        if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


  static void downloadCallback(
      String id, DownloadTaskStatus status, int progress) {
    final SendPort send =
    IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port')!;
    send.send([id, status, progress]);
  }
```

Now rebuild your app and test. download files will work now.