# Flutter inAppWebview download file from datatable export

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to export data from datatable like [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) using [inAppWebview package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) but the download failed because the URL is using BLOB, I try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62116620/6412375) answer but still unable to download that file. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known issue ([Download Blob file from Website inside Android WebViewClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892390/download-blob-file-from-website-inside-android-webviewclient/48954970#48954970)).
There is another question about .pdf files with exactly the same problem [Flutter WebView blob pdf download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64865972/flutter-webview-blob-pdf-download/64902313#64902313).
I have updated my answer to support extension that depends on mimeType that blob has instead of hardcoding it for .pdf. You can try it.
You would need to map the mimeType that you get e.g. `application/vnd.ms-excel` to `.xlsx` etc.